# How do I install perl's Text::Markdown::Discount on Strawberry Perl?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

When ever I try to `cpanp install Text::Markdown::Discount` on Strawberry Perl I get

```
cp lib/Text/Markdown/Discount.pm blib\lib\Text\Markdown\Discount.pm
    ( cd discount-2.1.2; CC='cc -fPIC' sh configure.sh; make )
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

[I see a lot of others are having this same problem.](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Text-Markdown-Discount-0.02;reports=1;os=mswin32) Can `T:M:D` be installed on Strawberry Perl?

You also can not install T:M:D with ppm:

```
PPM> install Text::Markdown::Discount
Install package 'Text-Markdown-Discount?' (y/N): y
Installing package 'Text-Markdown-Discount'...
Error installing package 'Text-Markdown-Discount': Could not locate a PPD file f
or package Text-Markdown-Discount
```

Comment: The author should not hardcode `cc`, but use the toolchain in a OS-independent fashion. `use Config; $Config{cc}` would be a good start. `ExtUtils::CBuilder` could be useful.

Answer (score -2):

I installed Text::Markdown::Discount with these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/sekimura/text-markdown-discount.git

cd text-markdown-discount/

perl Makefile.PL

make

make test

sudo make install
```

Comment: Your use of `/` in path names and `sudo` indicates that you're not doing this on Windows. The question was specifically about [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), a Perl environment for Windows.

Comment: You're writing an answer to a question that's six years old.

Comment: @Borodin That's not a problem per se; I'd love to see old questions get answered if it is a good answer.